Why does ISA includes instruction for logical operation?
I'm a junior student in Electronic Engineering.
Recently, I learned about Gödel's incompleteness theorem. One of the concepts related to this theorem is Gödel numbering, which shows that every logical operation can be converted into an arithmetic operation.
This leads me to think that an Instruction Set Architecture (ISA) might not need to include specific logical operation instructions, as these operations could theoretically be performed using arithmetic operations instead.
I assume that the reason for including direct logical operation instructions is that they are much faster than performing logical operations through arithmetic operations, but I'm not entirely sure.

The reason for including anything in an instruction set is performance. mov is Turing-complete.

@NaïmFavier  Thank you! your link about mov is quite interesting!

Try implementing a function unsigned int bit_and (unsigned int x, unsigned int y). The best I can come up with (and it is not trivial) is O(n) for n bit numbers, while addition can be implemented in O(log n) n-bit bit operations. So there is a massive difference in performance.

Whenever something is done very frequently and can be done much more quickly by making it part of the instruction set, it should be. The first generations of microprocessors had very limited amounts of transistors and couldn't implement many instructions. Nonetheless bitwise operations were important enough to be included. Multiplication was not included, because it needed too many transistors. Modern CPUs have approximately infinite transistors to play with, and have included things like multiplication and even AES encryption.

Imo in digital electronics arithmetic operations are made of logical operations.
And how do you build a digital circuit which performs a arithmetic operation without being a subset of a logical operation?

I do not even understand a digital circuit which performs [an] arithmetic operation without being a subset of a logical operation - how can a circuit be part of an operation? How does this answer Why include both if one can be expressed in terms of the other??

@greybeard you can easily build a circuit made of transistors which would return the negation of a input signal.It is not easy to build a circuit made of transistors which would return the sum of 2 bits(2 input signals) without having already made a circuit which performs a logical operation.In digital electronics the arithmetic operations are made of logical operations , not vice versa.

Implementation of operations isn't ISA.
